# Sorting data from a given column where the sort order is after a dot

Tags: mysql-8.0, mariadb-10.3

I have the following query:

```
SET @counter = -1;
UPDATE domains SET domains.order = @counter := @counter + 1
ORDER BY domains.extension ASC;
```

Where the column `extension` is comprised of TLD's.

Now we consider TLD's as after the final dot, so for example if the address here was `stackoverflow.co.uk` `.co` is the second level domain and `.uk` is the TLD.

So in the column extensions you'll have `.co`, `.uk` and `.co.uk`.

We pretend to order everything by the value after the dot, the TLD, but the above command sorts by first character. Is there a solution to sort by first character after the last dot? Thank you.

[MYSQL/MariaDB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(domains.extension, '.', -1)
```

[Docs here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/substring_index/).

Comment: Kudus! Worked beautifully. Thank you.